# Arial font missing -- browsers showing most text as italic or bold

Tags: windows-7, windows, browser, fonts

Today I opened up my browser (Opera 11.60) and noticed that all of the font was italicized. There are still some text that isn't italicized, but most of the text is italicized. I then opened up Firefox 9.0.1, and all of the font was bold. I looked at the Fonts in the Control Panel, and I have `Arial Black`, `Arial Bold`, `Arial Bold Italic`, `Arial Italic`.

So, does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: it might be an added font, messing things up.

Answer (score 1):

So downloading and reinstalling the fonts [found in this post at sevenforums.com](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/60852-whats-wrong-my-fonts.html) solved my problem! Just unzip the attachment, and copy over to the `C:\Windows\Fonts`.

Answer (score 0):

So, try:

Go to Fonts Directory, Delete Regular Arial Font, reboot, and reinstall it.

Solved the problem for some lucky users.

Source: [See Here Solved](http://www.ozzu.com/mswindows-forum/resolved-all-default-fonts-are-italic-t87269.html)

Comment: I tried deleting the Arial Black font, rebooting, and then reinstalling it as an Admin, and it still didn't work.